# Duplicate dataLayer objects [GTM]

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In a specific page (for not all) I see some objects duplicated in GTM dataLayer as given below.

[image: error image]

Here is the reproducable version of the code:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('consent', 'default', {
    'ad_storage': 'denied',
    'analytics_storage': 'denied'
});
window.dataLayer.push({customerID: "", language:"en", em:""});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var gtmcode = '${gtmCode}',
        gtmscript = "(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer', '" + gtmcode + "');";
        eval(gtmscript);
});
```

What could be causing this problem, is this issue backend related?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem, does it break your tags?

dataLayer is an **array of objects** and it is normal to add new objects with same keys to the dataLayer. In your GTM you use either dataLayer variable Version 1 (takes into account only the **currently added object** = last added) or Version 2 (aggregates the array into one object and update keys and values so **only the last added values for those keys remain** - in your example for event=consent, only the second values remain).
This ensures that you don't have to worry about objects added multiple times into dataLayer.

More on DL variable in GTM: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/data-layer-variable-versions-explained/